# unable to apply style.left to imges

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to create a slideshow with pure javascript.In that I am able to move first image with javascript.But when I am trying to move second image and applying left to that second image that left is not being applied to that second image.Here is my code.Could anyone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        #slideshow
        {
            width: 600px;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 100px;
            background-color: green;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #slideshow img
        {
            visibility: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var images = ["first","second","third"];
        var i = 0;
        window.addEventListener("load",slideshow,true);
        function slideshow()
        {
            var currentImage = images[i];
            var nextImage = images[i+1];
            var parentLeft = document.getElementById("slideshow").offsetLeft;
            var imgWidth = document.getElementById("second").width;
            document.getElementById(currentImage).style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById(nextImage).style.visibility = "visible"; 
            document.getElementById(nextImage).style.left = (parentLeft - imgWidth)+"px";
            document.getElementById(nextImage).style.left = "50px";
            move(currentImage,nextImage);
        }
        function move(currentImage,nextImage)
        {
            var currentImageLeft = document.getElementById(currentImage).offsetLeft;
            var nextImageLeft = document.getElementById(nextImage).offsetLeft;          
            document.getElementById(currentImage).style.left = (currentImageLeft + 5)+"px";
            document.getElementById(nextImage).style.left = (nextImageLeft + 5)+"px";
            setTimeout(function(){move(currentImage,nextImage)},4);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slideshow">
            <img src="1.jpg" id="first" width="600px" height="200px" />
            <img src="2.jpg" id="second" width="600px" height="200px" />
            <img src="3.jpg" id="third" width="600px" height="200px" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You never count `i` up?

Comment: var nextImage = images[i+1];

Comment: But you got 3 images. And you apply to `nextImage` twice?

Comment: I struck at second image.If I am able to move second image,then i can move third one too